# Numeric value of ULong.MaxValue is considered an overflow in Visual Basic.NET

Tags: vb.net, overflow, ulong

In Visual Basic.NET ULong.MaxValue=18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

The following code runs fine:

```
Dim a As ULong = ULong.MaxValue
```

The following code returns an overflow error on the number

```
Dim b As ULong = 18446744073709551615
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: You need to add the `UL` suffix to the literal number to indicate that it is Unsigned Long and not just Long. `Dim b As ULong = 18446744073709551615UL`

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried L.  Please post as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler assumes that any whole number too large to be an `Integer` is a `Long` and of course your number won't fit in a `Long`. You need to add the UL suffix to the literal number to indicate that it is `ULong` and not just `Long`.

```
Dim b As ULong = 18446744073709551615UL
```